# run time ClassNotFoundException for classes in a transitive dependency shared by to dependencies

Tags: java, spring, maven, cassandra

I have a maven project that uses springboot, and spring data cassandra which includes datastax's cassandra driver, which works fine.

When I introduce a 3rd library (let's call it `new-library`) dependency which shares a transitive dependency with the cassandra driver (`com.typesafe:config`), the driver throws a ClassNotFoundException for a class in that transitive dependency.

Now the dependency is the same version in the cassandra driver as the 3rd library.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>new-library</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Without `new-library`, `mvn dependency:tree` shows `com.typesafe:config:jar:1.4.1` showing up under the datastax driver.

```
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra:jar:2.5.4:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.3.9:compile
|  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-cassandra:jar:3.2.4:compile
|     +- com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core:jar:4.11.3:compile
|        +- com.typesafe:config:jar:1.4.1:compile
...
```

When I add in the `new-library` dependency, that vanishes from mvn tree but shows up under `new-library`.

```
\- com.example:new-library:jar:1.0.0:compile
   +- com.typesafe:config:jar:1.4.1:compile
```

I've tried setting an exclusion in the `new-library` dependency - that did not work.

```xml
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
                    <artifactId>config</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
```

I also tried adding `com.typesafe:config` as a standalone dependency with and without scope set to runtime.  That did not work.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
            <artifactId>config</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

exception

```java
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.config.DriverConfigLoader]: Factory method 'cassandraDriverConfigLoader' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/typesafe/config/ConfigOriginFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    ... 198 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/typesafe/config/ConfigOriginFactory
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.config.typesafe.TypesafeDriverConfig.<clinit>(TypesafeDriverConfig.java:45) ~[java-driver-core-4.11.3.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.config.typesafe.DefaultDriverConfigLoader.<init>(DefaultDriverConfigLoader.java:196) ~[java-driver-core-4.11.3.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.config.typesafe.DefaultDriverConfigLoader.<init>(DefaultDriverConfigLoader.java:182) ~[java-driver-core-4.11.3.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.config.typesafe.DefaultProgrammaticDriverConfigLoaderBuilder.build(DefaultProgrammaticDriverConfigLoaderBuilder.java:244) ~[java-driver-core-4.11.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cassandra.CassandraAutoConfiguration.cassandraDriverConfigLoader(CassandraAutoConfiguration.java:117) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.typesafe.config.ConfigOriginFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

so it turns out the 3rd library was being built by a very old version of gradle.   I upgrade gradle there and rebuilt and retried this project and the problem was resolved.   I guess gradle created an invalid pom of some sort.